# How to perform an exclusive search in windows?

Tags: windows-7, search

How do I do an exlusive search in Windows 7?  For example, I want the search to return everything EXCEPT `.jpg` files.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `NOT` operator in the folder search bar (the operator is case-sensitive).

[image: Unfiltered Pictures]

[image: Filtered Pictures]

Note that I did this in my Pictures directory to illustrate the filter.  If you do this in a higher level directory you get *all files* that are not JPEGs, so there can be quite a few results.

There are several other search operators explained in [Advanced tips for searching in Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Advanced-tips-for-searching-in-Windows).

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would use Powershell to do it:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\ -Include foo.* -Exclude *.jpg -Recurse
```